# splitting xml files into multiple xml file using awk on Windows

Tags: xml, windows, awk, syntax-error

I found the awk command to be able to split an input xml file into multiple xml files and it works great in Linux environment.

```
awk 'BEGIN {NUM=0}; /xml version="1.0"/ {NUM++; filename=NUM"Output.xml"}; {print >filename}' Inputfile.xml
```

However, I am trying to run it on Windows command prompt and got the following syntax error. Do you know how I can modify this command to run successfully on Windows?

```
awk "BEGIN {NUM=0}; /xml version="1.0"/ {NUM++; filename=NUM"Output.xml"}; {print >filename}" Inputfile.xml

awk: BEGIN {NUM=0}; /xml version=1.0/ {NUM++; filename=NUMOutput.xml}; {print >filename}
awk:                                                                ^ syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {NUM=0}; /xml version="1.0"/ {NUM++; filename=NUM "Output.xml"; print filename}; {print ^> filename}' Inputfile.xml
```

But you have a problem in your code, better change to this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {NUM=0; filename=NUM "Output.xml";}; /xml version="1.0"/ {NUM++; filename=NUM "Output.xml"; } {print ^> filename }' Inputfile.xml
```

`filename` is not initialized before the code meet first `xml version="1.0"` line, it will throw error.
So it's better initialize it in the `BEGIN` block.

Or just:

```
awk 'BEGIN {NUM=0} /xml version="1.0"/ {NUM++} {print ^> NUM "Output.xml"}' Inputfile.xml
```

Otherwise there's only `>` in your code need to escape, which is to add `^` before it in `cmd`.
Through my years using `awk` within batch file or under `cmd`, I gradually come to prefer using single quotes outside the awk code, and make note those characters need to escape. -- The characters within a pair of double quotes need not to escape, others need.

Another choice, many times a better one, is to save code in a file like `xcode1.awk` and use `-f` switch like `awk -f xcode1.awk Inputfile.xml` to invoke it.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by creating a test.awk file as you suggest with content - BEGIN {NUM=0}; /xml version="1.0"/ {NUM++; filename=NUM"TestResult.xml";} {print >filename} and then run it as awk -f test.awk Inputfile.xml.  The script logic works fine but it's the Windows double quote handling that's the issue so putting it into a script seems to work.  Thanks!